# migrating codeigniter from 1 server to another

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I was trying to migrate a codeigniter application on one server to another but i am getting HTTP 500 error on godaddy and 404 error on dreamhost.

I have transferred the files to root directory and uploaded the database. I have changed the config and database php files, but its still not working.

The `.htaccess` file consists the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  #incluye el / final
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]  
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I don't know how the `htaccess` works. Please help me with the issue.

The following are the snapshots of the erros:

[image]

[image]

Comment: htaccess file really shouldnt be the problem. Double check your base / site url configs. Check your spelling Make sure your base controller is right

Comment: Post your base controller please. The one with your page that you are trying to open. I doubt the htacess is your problem

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem was something else. The problem was with the php-mysqli driver.